# Migrating classic depot to streams depot

Tags: perforce, perforce-stream

We want to migrate our classic depot to stream depot.
Is it possible? Can anyone please share any docs for that ?
i can just import the classic depot project to stream depot, But , it wont get the history of files once i move it to streams depot. Is it possible to migrate it completely. Do we have any easy method to do that ?

Answer (score 1):

Files can be duplicated between depots (with full history) via the `p4 duplicate` command.  You can take advantage of this to migrate a "classic" branching structure into a stream depot, provided that the files are placed in locations that correspond correctly to the stream path definitions.

Since there is not an automated mechanism for translating classic branch paths to stream paths, classic->stream migrations are not recommended as typical practice, and are usually carried out under the supervision of a consultant who will have the expertise needed to understand both your existing branching structure and a hypothetical stream-based version of the same thing, and come up with a mapping for every depot file from one to the other.

The standard recommendation for companies moving to streams is to keep your existing projects in their existing classic depots, and start using streams with a new project so you're building your codeline structure in streams from scratch rather than trying to refactor it after the fact.

Comment: Thanks Sam, We recently migrated from X version control to perforce. And developers are facing some difficulty with perforce client setup and branch spec setup ...etc. we found that there are lot of advantages of stream depot than classic depot and decided to migrate it to stream depot.In classic depot we don't have all branches at same level.In streams due to implicit integration technique i guess we need to have all branches at same level. My guess is correct ?

Comment: Yes, all streams in a depot have the same "directory depth" relative to the depot root.

Comment: 'p4 dupicate' is undocumented in perforce. Is That to safety to use it ? and I need to make sure I don't end up having any unanticipated problems as a result.

Comment: See `p4 help undoc` for more on `p4 duplicate`.

Comment: Sam, I did not find much info there... As its just showing that it is unsupported. But,i am able to create duplicate revisions successfully. Here i just want to know why it is not documented?  Is it safer to use it ?

Comment: As I stated, the entire thing you're attempting to do is unsupported, which basically means that if you hurt yourself you're on your own.  I haven't ever had any problems using `duplicate` personally.

Comment: After creating the streams. Can we avoid to show the classic depot file changes in cl description instead of obliterating the files in classic depot? Because we don't want to obliterate the files immediately after creating streams. We want everyone comfortable with streams then after we want to obliterate the classic depot changes. 
Can we have a way to show only stream files in cl description ?

Comment: Removing `list` access to them in the protection table might work, but then people can't use the classic depot.